# Forcing image to retain its original size upon loading

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am creating a splash-screen for android application and added a image to it but upon opening the app , image is stretching , how can i make that image retain its aspect ratio and not stretch at all

here's my Styles.xml code , image = icon.png

[Styles.xml](https://pastebin.com/vrvciZK9)

Comment: Why would you want to set an icon as background ?

Comment: its a high res icon , i just need to know how can i resize it , Is it possible by editing Styles.xml

Comment: As your image is stretching, where do you wanna place it ? At the center ?

Comment: yes , at center!

Comment: Check my answer below please

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImageView` add:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: there is no ImageView for SplashScreen's image , have a look at my Styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a xml file using `layer-List` (`splash.xml`) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"></item>
    <item>
       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon" android:gravity="fill" android:antialias="true" android:dither="true"></bitmap>
    </item>
 </layer-list>
```

Add this `splash.xml` as background of your *SplashScreen*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: it is solving the problem , but i have a square image , how can i make it fit without losing its aspect ratio , gravity doesn't have any "centerCrop" setting